# How to exclude GlobalSuppressions.cs from analysis in VS2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, code-analysis

Currently I'm trying the new Code Analysis features in Visual Studio 2015. This feature enables developers to suppress active issues. Issues are suppressed using the SuppressMessageAttribute, which can be applied in the source code itself or in a separate suppressions file, which Visual Studio creates in the project root by the name 'GlobalSuppressions.cs'.

However when I use such a (generated) suppression file, this file itself becomes subject to analysis itself and subsequently causing analyses errors. I cannot find anything about preventing this. Is there any way to exclude this 'GlobalSuppressions.cs' file from Code Analysis altogether?

Perhaps noteworthy, I'm using the NuGet package [StyleCop.Analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.Analyzers/) for additional analyzer rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

- Put this at the top of GlobalSuppressions.cs `// <auto-generated />`
- For just for StyleCop:

Alter the csproj to have  for the file:

```
  <Compile Include="GlobalSuppressions.cs">
    <ExcludeFromStyleCop>True</ExcludeFromStyleCop>
 </Compile>
```

Comment: The first option works best. The second works only for the old StyleCop extension, however it does not work for the NuGet-paackage StyleCop.Analyzers.

Comment: Ah that's interesting to note when I go through migration. Thanks!